# Javascript AJAX pending request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create a function which when You send a http(s) request. If there is 5 or more ongoing requests, you have to wait until one
of them is completed then you can process next request.
i have done this so far

```
 function makerequest ("/routeplanner/data","GET",sucess,error) 
{ 


var xmlHttp = new XMLhttpRequest(); 


var count =0;

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlHttp.readystate ==4 && xmlHttp.statue ==200) {
success (xmlHttp.responseText);}

else if (xmlHttp.status !=200 &&count !=3){
count++;
xmlHttp.open(method,url,true);

else if (count ==3){
error("you have reached the maximum number of tries")
}
}
xmlHttp.open("GET","/routeplanner/data",true);

xmlHttp.send(null)
}
```

any idea how that can be done in pure JS.

Comment: Does this work? The first line doesn't look like valid javascript.

Comment: no it doesn't , i have an error

Comment: Please add your error to your question.

Comment: `if (xmlHttp.readystate == && xmlHttp.statue ==200 {`? Sorry, but your code looks a mess. Fix it and then come back with an actual question.

Comment: i have fix it , it was a sytax error along with readstate ==4

Comment: Yeah but `xmlHttp.statue` doesn't even exist. It should be `status`... I mean, if you expect people in here to help you, at least put some effort in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax issues with your example code aside, you need to keep track of the `count` outside of the function that does the check.

```
// Store this outside of the function
var activeRequests = 0;
var maximumRequests = 5;

function makeRequest(...) {
  // Quit early if the maximum has been exceeded
  if (activeRequests >= maximumRequests) {
    error('too many requests');
    return;
  }
  ...
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    ...
    // Decrease the number of active requests when one is completed
    --activeRequests;
    ...
  };
  ...
  // Increase the number of active requests when one starts
  ++activeRequests;
  ...
}
```